# Missing group price after migration M2

Tags: magento2, product, database

**After migration From Magento1 to Magento2 Group Product Price Missing**

[image]

**I have followed below step** Not solve this issue plz help me

**Step 1** Run query in M1 DB and download resule csv file (without coloumn name)
sql:

```
SELECT cpe.`entity_id`, cq.`qty`,cpgp.`website_id`, cpgp.`all_groups`,cpgp.`customer_group_id`,cpgp.`value` FROM `catalog_product_entity` as cpe RIGHT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_group_price` as cpgp ON cpgp.`entity_id` = cpe.`entity_id` LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` as cq on cq.`product_id` = cpe.`entity_id` WHERE cpe.`entity_id` IS NOT NULL
```

**Step 2** import this csv file in M2 db with specific coloumn order (entity_id,qty,website_id,all_groups,customer_group_id,value)

Comment: reindex and check it.

Comment: you need to remigrate your data again and check it